# Requirejs optimizer and locale setting that is set dynamically

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, requirejs, r.js, grunt-contrib-requirejs

I am using requirejs optimizer (r.js) through grunt and here is my requirejs config :

```
requirejs.config
  baseUrl: '/scripts'
  locale: window.localStorage.getItem('locale') || null
  ...
```

The thing is that the grunt r.js plugin (https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-requirejs) throw an error everytime I try to use a variable inside my requirejs config.

```
The main config file cannot be used because it cannot be evaluated correctly while running in the optimizer. Try only using a config that is also valid JSON, or do not use mainConfigFile and instead copy the config values needed into a build file or command line arguments given to the optimizer.
```

Have you managed to use a variable as a locale and r.js at the same time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `locale` setting acquires a real value only at runtime. For parts of RequireJS' config that can only be given values at runtime, what I do is:

1. Just call `require.config` (or `requirejs.config`) once with the information which is static. The config does not contain any variables. I point `r.js` to this static information.
2. At runtime, I have at least one additional call to `require.config` that sets those values that are to be computed. RequireJS combines multiple calls to `require.config` into one configuration.

`r.js` will only use the *first* configuration it recognizes in a file. So you may be able to just split your single `requirejs.config` call into a static and dynamic part and leave them in the same file.